# We have an own wallet but we don't have an idea how to connect this to other sites?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, javascript, nodejs

I had an Wallet created by Own.I need to connect that wallet with active sites like Metamask.If we want to connect the Metamask with Site means we call `window.ethereum` default as a trigger comment.

Likewise Which comment should i use for connect My own created wallet with Active Sites or using as same `window.ethereum` how to connect my own wallet.

Guide me